# Python Logic Issue

Tags: python, sqlite, elementtree

I am using elementtree to parse an XML file and placing the data into an sqlite database. I have come across a problem that I believe could be solved by some better logic, that I am most likely missing. I am getting a `local variable 'netbios_name' referenced before assignment` error, this is the case for the `operating_system` variable as well. I understand why I am getting it but I am not certain on how to resolve the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Example XML Data**

```
<ReportHost name="192.168.26.11"><HostProperties>
<tag name="HOST_END">Sat Apr 25 11:36:08 2015</tag>
<tag name="LastUnauthenticatedResults">1223744168</tag>
<tag name="Credentialed_Scan">false</tag>
<tag name="policy-used">Advanced Scan</tag>
<tag name="patch-summary-total-cves">5</tag>
<tag name="cpe-0">cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_2003_server::sp2 -&gt; Microsoft Windows 2003 Server Service Pack 2</tag>
<tag name="system-type">general-purpose</tag>
<tag name="operating-system">Microsoft Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2</tag>
<tag name="mac-address">00:1f:19:f5:14:34</tag>
<tag name="traceroute-hop-2">192.168.26.11</tag>
<tag name="traceroute-hop-1">10.100.1.249</tag>
<tag name="traceroute-hop-0">10.100.1.254</tag>
<tag name="host-ip">192.168.26.11</tag>
<tag name="netbios-name">PLUTOAPP01</tag>
<tag name="HOST_START">Sat Apr 25 10:20:43 2015</tag>
</HostProperties>
```

**Example Problem Code**

```
def get_details(nessus_file):
    db = sqlite3.connect('database.sqlite')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    try:
        tree = ET.parse(nessus_file)
        for reporthost in tree.findall('/Report/ReportHost'):
            host = reporthost.get('name')
            for tag in reporthost.findall('.//HostProperties/tag'):
                if tag.get('name') == 'netbios-name':
                    netbios_name = tag.text
                elif tag.get('name') == 'operating-system':
                    operating_system = tag.text
                else:
                    pass
                #The if statements above^ are causing my issues along with the execute statement below
                cursor.execute('INSERT INTO hosts(host, netbios_name, operating_system) VALUES(?,?,?)', (host, netbios_name, operating_system,))

            for item in reporthost.findall('ReportItem'):
                sev = item.get('severity')
                name = item.get('pluginName')
                description = item.findtext('description')
                pluginid = item.get('pluginID')

                cursor.execute('INSERT INTO vulns(pluginName, severity, description, pluginID) VALUES(?,?,?,?)', (name,sev,description,pluginid,))
                for cve in item.getiterator('cve'):
                    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO cves(cve) VALUES(?)', (cve.text,))
        db.commit()
        db.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        exit()

create_db()
get_details('file.nessus')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to insert both the netbios name and the operating system *for each such tag*. You need to move the insert out of the `for` loop you have, and set defaults for both variables:

```
netbios_name = operating_system = None
for tag in reporthost.findall('.//HostProperties/tag'):
    if tag.get('name') == 'netbios-name':
        netbios_name = tag.text
    elif tag.get('name') == 'operating-system':
        operating_system = tag.text
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO hosts(host, netbios_name, operating_system) VALUES(?,?,?)', (host, netbios_name, operating_system,))
```

This would insert `NULL` values if either value is not present in the XML document.

Since you are looking for just the two tags, you can also just search for the specific elements by filtering on the attribute value:

```
netbios_name = reporthost.find('.//HostProperties/tag[@name="netbios-name"]')
netbios_name = netbios_name and netbios.text
operating_system = reporthost.find('.//HostProperties/tag[@name="operating-system"]')
operating_system = operating_system and operating_system.text
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO hosts(host, netbios_name, operating_system) VALUES(?,?,?)', (host, netbios_name, operating_system,))
```

The `[@attrib="value"]` syntax instructs ElementTree to look for a tag with that attribute and value; the `.find()` method finds the first such tag or returns `None` if it is missing. The next line then leaves the variable set to `None` or extracts the text from the found tag.

Comment: thanks for the prompt response. I had tried the execute statement outside the loop (without setting default values) and was getting the same results. :) always so simple